# Triggering a change event for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, event-handling

I have several select menus that needs that need to have their change events triggered on page load, so that they can automatically use the change behavior from an `on('change', ...)` handler.

I have it working fine in Firefox, but apparently this doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

**Example**

```
var changeEvent  = new Event('change')
input.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

I have tried finding alternatives in IE, and this is the closest I've come:

```
ie_event = document.createEvent('change')

ie_event.initEvent('change', function(e) {
    ...
}, false);

document.dispatchEvent(ie_event);
```

*The above is from [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/893254/JavaScript-Triggering-Event-Manually-in-Internet-E), but it doesn't tell me what to put in the ellipses.

Can someone tell me what's wrong, point me in the right direction, or give me an example?

Comment: You need to show your HTML and describe exactly which interaction you're trying to have an event for.  As you describe things initially, I don't even understand why you're trying to create a new event rather than use an existing event that is already triggered.  This [MDN page on `createEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) indicates that it is not supported in IE.

Comment: I'll update. I need to create a change event on the page load, not just when I change the select box.

Comment: Like I said, please show us the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be of any help?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#select").on("change",function(){
             //do something
          });

          $("#select").trigger("change");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `.trigger()` is the only thing I could get to work across browsers. Thanks.